# navigate('/') doesn't navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router Dom `v6`. So for my web application, I created a Redux action in `userAction` called `logoutUser`, and in view `dashboard.jsx`, I added a logout button that should navigate me to the home page `('/')`. My problem is that clicking on logout does nothing, is my code wrong?

userAction.js:

```
export const logoutUser = (navigate) => {
    return () => {
        sessionService.deleteSession();
        sessionService.deleteUser();
        navigate('/');
    }
}
```

dashboard:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const Dashboard = ({logoutUser}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledButton bg={colors.red} to="#" onClick={()=>logoutUser(navigate)}>
        Logout
      </StyledButton>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logoutUser` returns a function instead of executing the tasks you want. You either change it to:

```
export const logoutUser = (navigate) => {  
   sessionService.deleteSession();
   sessionService.deleteUser();
   navigate('/');
}
```

Or change your `onClick` part to the code below so you execute the function returned by `logoutUser`:

```
onClick={()=>logoutUser(navigate)()}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `logoutUser` is meant to be an action, then you need to *actually* dispatch that action to your redux store. This assumes you have correctly added the thunk (or other similar asynchronous action middleware).

Example:

```
export const logoutUser = (navigate) => () => {
  sessionService.deleteSession();
  sessionService.deleteUser();
  navigate('/');
};
```

...

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledButton
        bg={colors.red}
        to="#"
        onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser(navigate))}
      >
        Logout
      </StyledButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```